# Display a tag before the menu list content

Tags: menus, tags

Is that possible to insert a text before the menu items? In this case, I want to lead a `<h3>` tag for the list content (like a menu title). I tried the `if/else` to recognize that the menu have content and show the title. But if the menu have no content, so it should not have to display the title.

Here it is:

```
$args = array(
  'menu'        => 'Destination • South America',
  'echo'        => false,
  'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
);

if (empty($args)) {
  echo "<li></li>";
}else{
  echo "<h3>South America</h3>";
}
echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $args ), '<li><a>');
```

Because I have content, so It should output:

**South America**
Argentina
Brazil
Chile
Colombia
Equador
Uruguay
Venezuela

If I would not have any content, so it should not display the **South America**

Thank you!

Comment: Why aren't you just using the "South America" or other parent text as a parent menu item, others as child item ? The thing you are trying to achieve will only comes up handy when the "Argentina, Chile" etc are being included dynamically in the menu.

Comment: That's right. I'm using Argentina, Brazil and other countries as the menu. The "South America" title appears to identify the countries in the menu. However, if I remove all the items in the menu, the "South America" (the `h3`) should not be display!

Comment: I think he's trying to say this is a sub navigation menu on internal pages, and it shows up everywhere. I'll add an answer to this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Put this function into your theme's `function.php` file.

```
function is_tree($pid) { // $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
    global $post;
    $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    foreach($anc as $ancestor) {
            if(is_page() && $ancestor == $pid) {
                    return true;
            }
    }
    if(is_page()&&(is_page($pid))) { return true; /*we're at the page or at a sub page*/ }
    else { return false; /*we're elsewhere*/ }
}
```

Then wrap your code in:

```
<?php
  // put the parent id or in this case, South America's id as the parent-id
  if(is_tree('parent-id')) {
    // output your menu
  }
?>
```